# Splitting on regex and keep delimiters with following regex match with Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split this text:

```
"Hi stackoverflow.I need to split these sentences.By full stop."
```

into something like this:

```
["Hi stackoverflow.", "I need to split these sentences.", "By full stop."]
```

I've tried the following:

```
import regex as re
text = "Hi stackoverflow.I need to split these sentences.By full stop."
re.findall(".*?\.[a-zA-Z0-9].*?", text)
```

but it returns:

```
['Hi stackoverflow.I', ' need to split these sentences.B']
```

Comment: You may use: `re.findall(r".+?\.(?=[A-Z]|$)", text)`

Comment: `re.findall(".+?\.", text)`

Comment: Could there be any dot in a number you would need to leave alone? For example `"Version 2.0"`? Would it be saver to assume a full stop is followed by uppercase letters? For example `re.split(r'(?<=\.)(?=[A-Z])', text)`